# Can't work addValueEventListener (Andriod Studio with Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, connection

I'm not good at using English. You may think my question is little hard to understand. 
(Sorry!! It's my first time to write in stackoverflow...)

I linked to Firebase (tool > firebase > realtime db > connect) and put the sdk Firebase said. 
And I wrote the Main code like below code. 
When I executed android emulator, there is no error (red line X, Warning sign X) 
But, data of the connected Firebase didn't get to android studio. 
Even onCancelled() didn't working. 
-> I think addValueEventListener can't working.. 
Please,, Help me

```java
package com.example.chart2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView textView;

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference cageStatus = database.getReference("cageStatus");

    private final String TAG = "MainActivityLog";

    int temp = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cageStatus = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress2);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.text2);

        cageStatus.child("temp").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                temp = (int) dataSnapshot.child("temp").getValue();
                progressBar.setProgress(temp);
                Log.d(TAG, "temp is: " + temp);
                textView.setText(temp+"%");
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM6V0.png)

Comment: Is any of the onDataChange or onCancelled even triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your database structure and what value you are trying to reach?.
probably you are  trying to retrive data from an invaild path.

also just noticed you have initialized your database twice
remove this second initialization and try again `cageStatus = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`

Comment: I see!! I put the image of firebase. Click 'enter image description here' below the code.  I will change the code!!